# JQuery Ajax calls in MVC app causing ever-increasing increasing Threads count

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, performance

We have an ASP.NET MVC web application and a javascript function that is called every 10 seconds (via setTimeout). This function makes an ajax call to one of our controller methods (using $.get), and that controller method returns a JsonResult, which is an object with about 5 or 6 int properties, which we then use to update some areas of the HTML in our page.

The problem that we're seeing is that if we monitor the number of Threads associated with the web server (when running locally under VS2013, I'm seeing it against iisexpress.exe, but on our live environment this is against iis), this Threads count is forever increasing, and never seems to go down.

As soon as I disable the $.get call in the JS, the Threads timeout stops increasing.

Is there a way to prevent this ever-increasing number of Threads being used?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to simply be down to the way in which something in one of our services wasn't being disposed of properly - nothing to do with Ajax/Jquery causing an issue.